# Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IDatabaseFacadeDependencies' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: c#

I'm trying to execute two stored procedures in a seeding class.

```
            int count=0;
            try{
                _context.Database.OpenConnection();
                var Count=_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXECUTE CheckIfThereAreUsers");
                count=Count;
            }
            catch{
                throw;
            }
            finally{
                _context.Database.CloseConnection();
            }
            if(count>0){
                return;
            }
            else{
                try{
                    _context.Database.OpenConnection();
                    string email="jujusafadinha@outlook.com.br";
                    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"EXECUTE SetNewUser {email}");
                }
                catch{
                    throw;
                }
                finally{
                    _context.Database.CloseConnection();
                }                
            }
        }
```

When the method is called, after a request to a controller, it gives the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.IDatabaseFacadeDependencies' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

The EF Core version is 5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you install the correct package for your specific database, and not just `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`? E.g. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` ?

Comment: I updated the MySQL package(version 8.0.22) and still got the error..